# 1996px div that only shows as much as screen size?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hello and thank you in advance for your help.
I'm working on the following component of a site:

The div content stretches over 1990px but I would like it to cut off based on the screen size. So if the user's screen size was 1200 they would only see 1200px of the div.

Right now the div content streches 1990px so it creates a sidescroll. I don't want to use a property like "overflow-x:hidden" as this will hurt usability and not allow the user to scroll on a smaller screen.

I would like this div to behave very much like a CSS background image in that it would only show as much as the user's screen size showed.

I'm stumped on this technique and have never done it so would greatly appreciate any and all tips and expertise.

Cheers!

Comment: Using Javascript would be possible for this project?

Comment: Sure would be I will integrating this into a responsive wordpress theme.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but after reading the question it doesn't stay clear for me... When the div is shown in a screen with, let's say, 1000px width the div will only show 1000px without scroll in the div nor the window, "loosing" the rest of the content, isn't it?

Comment: You want it to be cut off and not show a scrollbar, but it's a problem that it's cut off and you can't scroll it?

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS only, you can make two things:

1) Make the scroll bar appears on the container div, if the screen has no width enought, using  overflow-x:scroll; in the #top-photo-wrap div:

http://jsfiddle.net/k7b3K/

```
#top-photo-wrap {
background:#000;
/*height:204px;*/
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed Bold', sans-serif;
overflow-x:scroll; /* Makes the scroll bar horizontal appear*/
width:100%;
}
```

2) Make the div be "cutted" to the width of the screen, without showing more content, using  overflow-x:hidden; in the #top-photo-wrap div:

http://jsfiddle.net/DvCJZ/1/

```
#top-photo-wrap {
background:#000;
/*height:204px;*/
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed Bold', sans-serif;
overflow-x:hide; /* Makes the scroll bar horizontal desapear*/
width:100%;
 }
```

It is not very clear to me why you dont want to use overflow property... Did I missed something? :/

Comment: Thank you, I think I realized now that overflow-hidden is the ticket! I appreciate your answer and time!